# Where is org.gridgain.grid.util.ConcurrentHashMap8 located in Gridgain 6.0

Tags: gridgain

I am using Gridgain 6.0 and trying to run the Gridgain Compute Application in the Get Started tutorial. I got a ClassNotFoundException, complaining that org.gridgain.grid.util.ConcurrentHashMap8 cannot be found. Where is the class located?

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap8 is class from jdk8-backport library (GridGain library with some backported classes from JDK8 code base). It can be found in GridGain Nexus repository http://www.gridgainsystems.com:8085/nexus/content/repositories/external

You can use maven to automatically resolve all dependencies, just add repository link and specify GridGain edition you want to use ("gridgain-platform" in case of this snippet):

```
<repository>
    <id>GridGain External Repository</id>
    <url>http://www.gridgainsystems.com:8085/nexus/content/repositories/external</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>gridgain-platform</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found the location.